# function wrapper for if statement

Tags: php

I'm in a situation where I need to do a lot of logging in code. Got a function wrapper that calls needed function and logs related data along the way. But one thing I would be interested would be a wrapper for if statement. Or something that would allow me to set the logging of the outcome of the statement and other misc data in one place instead of dozens.

Something along the way of

```
$result = iff([isset($param1) && $param2 == 1]);

function iff($params) {

    if($params)
        $res = true;
    else
        $res = false;

    $log->save($miscData, $res);

    return $res;

}
```

Or something else that would allow me to set some sort of looging in one place. Looking for some ideas.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why do you need to log every single PHP statement like this? I can't think of functional or technical reason for this.

Comment: Well not down to every last one but at key places. The idea is to make a user friendly log to see what happened with the incoming call data and why as it passes trough many functions and statements and in the end the data is changed and transformed quite a lot.

Comment: This sounds to be like you are trying to build a PHP debugger...in PHP

Comment: Maybe didn't formulate everything perfectly and might have given the impression that I want to log eery single statement in project. No no, need it just for one speciffic model that receives a specific data package from external source and processes / transforms it etc. And for convinience I want to see what happened with it step by step as it goes throgh the model and what gets executed along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for **func_get_args** method.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

So your function (and example execution) would look like this:

> $result = iff(isset($param1), $param2 == 1);

```
function iff($params) {

    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    $res = true;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        if ($arg_list[$i] === false) {
            $res = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    $log->save($miscData, $res);

    return $res;
}
```

Please note that using this method allows you to pass arbitrary number of arguments into the function, each of which being a boolean value.